# Find all Accumulation points of semi-open interval

Tags: real-analysis

This problem is from Apostol Mathematical Analysis.

Let there be a semi-open interval (a,b]. What are the accumulation points of this set?

Unfortunately I could not able to find how to approach this problem. Can someone please guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: Thanks for your comment. Updated the question.

Comment: Do you know the definition of "accumulation point"? Have you seen similar examples, such as the set of accumulation points of an open or closed interval or a specific interval like $[0,1)$?

Comment: @GregMartin: Yes, I know the definition of accumulation point. Suppose S is a set. Then a is an accumulation point if for n-Ball(a;r) there exist atleast one point from S, distinct from a. B(a;r)-{a} $\cap$ S $\neq$ $\phi$.

Comment: Well with that defintion, wich points seem to you that are going to be ? no proofs just intuition , i dont know if you know this but the closure of the set is the set and its acumulation points

Comment: All the points in this set should be part of accumulation points. Suppose the set is (2,6]. Now I choose a=2.5 and r=. 1. Then, [2.4,2.6] is within the S.

Comment: Good start! Continuing with the example $(2,6]$: do you think $5.9$ is an accumulation point? $6$? $6.1$? $2$? $1.9$?

Comment: Yes. Because we can always get r in all the examples given such that all the points you mentioned are accumulation points.

Comment: The problem with this logic is that all open and closed sets also always have accumulation points. Only singleton sets will not have accumulation points.

Comment: *The problem with this logic* --- It will help to know that if $x$ is a point (could be in the set or not) for which $x$ is the center of some open ball and no point in the open ball except possibly $x$ is in the set, then $x$ will NOT be an accumulation point of the set. (I'm not sure if you would need to prove this or can assume it, as I don't have a copy of Apostol's book.) Every finite set has no accumulation points. Some infinite sets have no accumulation points, such as the set of integers. The sequence $1,$ $1/2,$ $1/3,$ $1/4, \; \ldots$ has exactly one accumulation point, namely $0.$

Comment: I got the answer. I didn't see "every" in the definition of n-balls. In my case (a,b] is the set of accumulation point. Because every point in the set follows the definition. But in other cases it might not be. Thanks everyone for guiding me towards the answer.